# Android: scroll part of screen horizontal and vertical

Tags: android, android-scrollview

on the screen I need to populate some report type of data. I need to do horizontal and vertical scroll for part of the screen.

How to achieve this task...?

[image]

I try following code but it not work:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:shrinkColumns="*"
            android:stretchColumns="**" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:text="Sl No."
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="4"
                    android:text="SubDivision"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="4"
                    android:text="Total No. of Works"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Completed"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="In-progress"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Award Cost(in Lakh)"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Value of Work Done(in Lakh)"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Payment Made(in Lakh)"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="3"
                    android:text="Balance to be Paid(in Lakh)"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:text="% Paid"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: If you need to use scroll use scrollView and TableView but you should not move presented table in 1:1 from desktop to mobile. You should only display  the most important informations

Comment: I am not moving any table. I want to do something which I mention in the photo.

Answer (score 1):

I had done something very similar, where i need to show excel sheet contents in listview that needs to be horizontally scroll-able.

I achieved this by putting `listview` inside `horizontalScrollView`.

something like below:

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
  // other attributes here.
  >
         <ListView
                 // listview attributes here
         />
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing.

Comment: see my question ...I mention the code..I am not able to see any thing on screen

Comment: but what is problem occuring with that xml.

Comment: I define some testView but not able to see anything on the screen

Comment: android:stretchColumns="**", this should be `*` i guess. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:shrinkColumns

Comment: after changing android:stretchColumns="**" to android:stretchColumns="*" it shows all the text but horizontal scroll not work. All the column are spared on width of screen.

Comment: add `android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true" ` in horizontalscrollview.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put it inside the scrollview like this

```
 <HorizontalScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/horizontalView" 
    android:layout_height="300dp"     
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tlGridTable" >   
        <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Column 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Column 2" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Column 3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Column 4" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Column 5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Column 6" />
</TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: @CoolMonster...if I will write the code into ScrollView then how I implement listView...???

Comment: @VinitVikash now check my answer i updated the asnwer

Comment: @CoolMonster...As I know you can not put listView inside ScrollView.

Comment: my answer is not formmated correctly now check its showing proper value. you can wrap it inside a linear layout then try

Comment: @CoolMonster...I try the above code ...it's not working

Comment: @VinitVikash check my new answer , i tested it, this is working.

Comment: @CoolMonster...thanx for ur effort...but if I will put listView out side the how I scroll listView horizontally after inserting data into listView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48455/discussion-between-coolmonster-and-vinit-vikash)